# Flutter list view navigation to categories

Tags: list, flutter

I'm learning Flutter. I have a ListView and I would like to make the list items clickable. My idea is that when the user clicks on an item, it will be directed to another screen. Each buttom should leads to different screen. I'm having trouble implementing it, I don't know what to use: gesture detector or ontap. What should I do? Should I use ListTile instead of ListView?[list view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oCQmh.jpg)[data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rW19j.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please [avoid uploading code as picture](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question).

Comment: [I have already replied to same problem here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69399831/how-to-make-listview-that-navigate-to-another-page-when-clicked/69400804#69400804)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a ListView.builder, you can use a ListTile to add an onTap.

```
ListView.builder(
  itemBuilder: (_, i) {
    return ListTile(
      title: Text('$i'),
      onTap: () {}, // Handle your onTap here. 
    );
  },
)
```

Comment: Is it possible to get the right code for the context. It's not accepting the Hotel ListViewClass

Answer (score 0):

well, you can use `Inkwell`. `ListView.builder( itemBuilder: (_, i) { return InkWell( onTap: (){}, child: ///widget, );  }, )` link [enter link description here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/InkWell-class.html)